# Как убрать тень statusbar?

Tags: android

Генерирую шаблон NavigationDrawer в Android Studio 2.1
Минимальная версия SDK: API 16(4.1)

И получаю тень на statusbar от toolbar:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально студия генерирует в стилях поле

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

И если его заменить на:

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

, то получаем нужный нам результат, но тогда drawer при раскрытии находится под statusbar:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос: как убрать тень, но также и оставить drawer в прежнем "правильном" состоянии?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставил android:fitsSystemWindows="false" для моего root layout - Coordinator Layout. В итоге проблема решена.
Ответ найден здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702896/how-to-remove-the-shadow-above-the-app-bar

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить к `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` параметр `app:elevation="0dp"`